CS50 Caesar code adds 16 to any cipher I input
The Caesar program is meant to take your text, add the inputted key to it and display the enciphered text. My code adds 16 to whatever key I input.
I have hardcoded the code to subtract 16 from the key; it fixed all the issues, but I have no idea what the real problem is.
CODE
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("./caesar (key here)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Make sure every character in argv[1] is a digit
        int c = argv[1][0];

        if(isdigit(c))
        {
            // Convert argv[1] from a `string` to an `int`
            // int k = argv[1];
            // Prompt user for plaintext
            string p = get_string("Input text to be coded:");
            int j = strlen(p);
            for(int i = 0 ; i < j ; i++)
            {
                //p[i] = p[i] + c;
                printf("%c" , p[i] + (c - 16));

            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("./caesar (key here)\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}


Please read What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? and How to debug small programs

The char code for '0' is 48. What is the 16 for?

If you mean '0' then you should use '0' and not some magic number. That will avoid using wrong values for said magic number.

Note that isdigit exhibits undefined behavior if its argument is not representable by unsigned char or is EOF, and in this code there's no guarantee that c is positive

re: usability.  If a user enters '5x' as the key and sees the program print the string ./caesar (key here), it is not at all clear what the error is or even that an error occurred (the program returns 0, so even the program is claiming there was no error!) You should give a decent error message explaining that all characters of the key must be digits.  And print that error message on stderr, not stdout.  Writing good error messages is hard; practice learning that skill now...and always.

It would seem that you want to add the numeric value represented by the argument passed to the program to each character in the input.
So your loop should be:
            for (int i = 0 ; i < j; i++)
            {
                printf("%c" , p[i] + (c - '0'));
            }

Where c - '0' gives you the numeric value the character c represents.
Moreover, you can reorder this to avoid some indentation by putting your guards both at the top of the main function (and returning 1 to indicate an error in these cases rather than 0).
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "./caesar (key here)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int c = argv[1][0];
    if (!isdigit(c)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "./caesar (key here)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int offset = c - '0';

    string p = get_string("Input text to be coded:");
    int j = strlen(p);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < j ; i++) {
        printf("%c" , p[i] + offset);
    }
}


This code doesn't wrap 'z' + 3 back to 'c'.  I would argue that error messages should be written to stderr, not stdout.  The code cannot do a shift of more than 9 because only one digit is used, which must be in the range '0' to '9'.

Okay, This was a really helpful teaching moment , i had no idea thats how it worked. (started coding 2 weeks ago hah). Another issue i m having is i am unable to grab an input larger than one charecter using my array , as its looking for one character , is there any solution i could implement?

Note that isdigit exhibits undefined behavior if its argument is not representable by unsigned char or is EOF, and in this code there's no guarantee that c is positive.

Thanks Everyone , i took all the input i got here and have managed to make the code. All i had to do was take C as an int instead or char , and i implemented a bit of code to check each term in array instead of the first , along with a bit of code to convert a value above 26 into a digit under 26

Then it would be great to show the working code, so others can better understand what the solution exactly was.

i have added an answer with the working code

    #include <cs50.h>
      #include <ctype.h>
      #include <math.h>
       #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
       int main(int argc, string argv[])
         {
        // Make sure program was run with just one command-line argument
    if (argc < 2)
    {
    printf("./ceaser (key here)\n");
    return 0;
      }
     else
   {
          // Make sure every character in argv[1] is a digit
     string m = argv[1];
    int c;
     sscanf(m, "%d", &c);

    for (int q = 0; q < strlen(m); m++)
    {
        if (isdigit(m[q]))
        {
            if (c <= 26)
            {
                // Convert argv[1] from a `string` to an `int`
                // int k = argv[1];
                // Prompt user for plaintext
                string p = get_string("Input text to be coded:");
                int j = strlen(p);
                for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                {
                    // p[i] = p[i] + c;
                    printf("%c", p[i] + c);
                }
                printf("\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                c = c % 26;
                string p = get_string("Input text to be coded:");
                int j = strlen(p);
                for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                {

                    printf("%c", p[i] + c);
                }
                printf("\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("./ceaser1 (key here)\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

}

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
